# How to set app path for android using Appium on a mac

Tags: rspec, appium

I wish to know how to set the app path for an android app on my mac. For iOS you can download the app and then in the desired capabilities you can provide the path.

I can't download the android version of the app onto my mac, but it is my understanding that I can use the android emulator and then install the app on it.

So how do I set the app path for this?

Answer (score 1):

Download the app on your Mac and add the app path under the capablities
For example in Ruby,

```
[caps]
appium-version = "1.1.0"
platformName = "Android"
platformVersion = "4.3"
deviceName = "Android Emulator"
app = "/Users/jitendra/Documents/projects/appiumAndroid/villageunity.apk"
```